# overloading > as member function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have written a relational operator < as member of class Test

```
bool Test::operator<(const Test& t) 
{
if (a<t)
      return true;
}
```

this code is in the header file, which I have included in my .cpp. However, when I compile my program, I get the following error:

```
test.h: 134:6: error: ‘a’ was not declared in this scope
```

Where do I declare 'a'? should I write it in my header file as Test& a? 
can you please help me fix this. thx!

Comment: What is `a` supposed to be?  A data member of class `Test`?  And why are you comparing it against a `Test` object?

Comment: The compiler is confused as to what you mean by `a` in `a<t`. So are we. Please explain.

Comment: The member operator only takes one argument, the right-hand side, and `x < y` invokes `x.operator<(y)`... so you need to compare your argument `t` to the instance itself.

Comment: @Kerrek That's correct but hopefully the OP will not run with this advice in the absolute literal sense, because an implementation like `*self<t` would be circular. :-)

Comment: @Ray: sure - since the OP is overloading a comparison operator, I'm sort of assuming that she knows that the purpose of this is to *define* the comparison semantics. By the way, in C++ it's called `this` (not "self") :-)

Comment: so when you say I need to compare my argument t to the instance itself, how do I do that?  class Test has 2 data members, int x_ and int y_. and a is a Test&. I want to make sure a::x<t::x_ and a::y is less than t::y_.

Comment: @Kerrick woops `s/self/this` how did THAT happen? :) Thanks. Ah, looks like the OP added the clarification we need.

Comment: @Kerrek, gender correction please :-)

Comment: @itcplpl: Just pick a name that's gender-specific and I won't have to guess. Otherwise it's 50/50!

Comment: and give up all my medallions on this site to restart ;-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to be defining how a Test object may be compared to another object of type Test but in your code you do not define how, only that "a" - whatever that is, is less than the other object.

```
class Test
{
public:
  Test(int myscore) { score = myscore; }
  bool operator<(const Test &t);
  int score;
}

bool Test::operator<(const Test &t) 
{
  // Is less than if score is smaller
  if(score < t.score)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Then in your program,

```
// ...

Test test1(4);
Test test2(5);

if(test1 < test2) std::cout << "4 is less than 5 by comparing objects\n";
else std::cout << "Failed!\n";
```

Comment: You should either `return false;` if the if is false or just use `return score < t.score` to begin with. Otherwise you'll get strange behavior.

Comment: Good catch @Voo, I was trying too hard to make the given code work. It should have been a compiler error when the function didn't return false.

Comment: If you make `operator<` a member of the class, you should probably make it `const`, too.